# How can I support Range-based for Statement for an internal list? ( c++ )

Tags: c++, iterator, stdlist

We have some widely used classes that wrap an internal std::list

```
template <class COLL_TYPE>
class OurColl
{
...
    private:
    std::list<COLL_TYPE> *m_pList;
```

I'd like to be able to use the range based for loops:

```
OurColl<int> listInts;
for ( int x : listInts )
{

}
```

This would have to iterate over the underlying m_pList.

I feel this question is different enough since it is closest to the answer provided by Chris Redford at the bottom of the question marked as duplicate.

Also, there is a bit of a twist since I am in a class with a template wrapping an internal list.

Comment: Please excuse my curiosity, but why do you have a *pointer* to a list? If you don't have a pointer, you could live by [the rule of zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero) which will make your life (and the class) simpler.

Comment: The important parts is that you need a `begin` and `end` functions that returns an object that is forward iterable. This is what the answers in the duplicate states (in a perhaps long-winded way). The simplest way to do it in this case is to use the wrapped lists iterators.

Comment: Does my example code look right?  This is very old code that is widely used in our projects, I'm hoping to make it a bit easier to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
  typename std::list<COLL_TYPE>::iterator begin()
   {
      return m_pList->begin();
   }
   typename std::list<COLL_TYPE>::iterator end()
   {
      return m_pList->end();
   }
   typename std::list<COLL_TYPE>::const_iterator begin() const
   {
      return m_pList->begin();
   }
   typename std::list<COLL_TYPE>::const_iterator end() const
   {
      return m_pList->end();
   }
```